# PHP Split String after specific occurances

Tags: php

I have the following string I'm trying to split into different variables based on specfic occurneces

```
Brodel8DARK HORSE COMICS
```

I'd like my end result to be

```
$user = Brodel

$index = 8

$publisher = DARK HORSE COMICS
```

I've tried playing around with some reg expressions but I'm a novice

This conditions will always be true

The user name will change (different number of Characters etc..)
The index will always be an integer but can grow to 3+ digits
The Publisher will always be in all caps

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can usernames have more than 1 number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the publisher doesn't start with a number, then this regex should work

```
/^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Z\s]+)$/
```

It's 0+ number of characters followed by 0+ digits and finally 0+ capital letters.

```
<?php

$string = 'Brodel8DARK HORSE COMICS';

if(preg_match('/^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Z\s]+)$/', $string, $matches) === 1){
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

This outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "Brodel8DARK HORSE COMICS"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Brodel"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "DARK HORSE COMICS"
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a try, publisher will never start with a number - thanks - Works Great Thanks!

Comment: what is difference with mine? I also posted mine before you? I don't know why users with high rep get more votes :)

Comment: @JasonOOO: I'll never understand the way people vote.  My answer started with 2 downvotes!

Comment: This might affect you in case if users with higher rep post answers, but votes should be for quality and correctness, please dont take my note as personal.

Comment: @JasonOOO no offense, I went to lunch and saw Rocket's answer first so I tried it.  Both of your answers are essentially the same and I thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
$string = 'Brodel8DARK HORSE COMICS';
preg_match("/^([^\d]+)(\d+)([A-Z\s]+)$/", $string, $match);

//print_r($match);
echo $publisher = $match[3];//DARK HORSE COMICS
?>
```